# Как работать с ссылками в Telegram Bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram

Для написания логики Telegram бота я использую библиотеку `python-telegram-bot`
Вопрос таков:

*- Как при клике на кнопку в InlineKeyboardButton - перенаправляло на сайт?*

*- Как при клике на кнопку в InlineKeyboardButton - перенаправляло в ЛС к живому человеку?*

```
bot.send_message(
    update.message.chat_id,
    text='Перенаправление на сайт... ➡️',
)
webbrowser.open('https://...', new=2)
```

Буду благодарна за помощь и советы)

Comment: А пример кода у вас есть?

Comment: @6NGY30E, да, добавила в вопрос

Answer (score 1):

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def default_test(message):
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    url_button = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Перейти на Яндекс", url="https://ya.ru")
    keyboard.add(url_button)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет! Нажми на кнопку и перейди в поисковик.", reply_markup=keyboard)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['contact'])
def getchatid(message):
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'https://t.me/%nickname%')  # так же можно "украсить" ссылку с помощью parse_mode
```